# FindDistribution from moments

Tags: distributions

There is a function `FindDistribution` that finds a distribution from the given data.

But what if I'm given moments and what to find a distribution.

Is there any function for this?

Thank you.

```
    j[x_] := Moment[JohnsonDistribution["SL", gamma, delta, 0, lambda],x];

    FindRoot[{j[1] == 1.2974425414, j[2] == 5.252267250245984, 
    j[3] == 112.50634898225843576187}, {{delta, 
    1.5}, {gamma, -1.2}, {lambda, 0.4}}, WorkingPrecision -> 250, 
    MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

It gives `Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {delta,gamma,lambda} = \ {1.5`,-1.2`,0.4`}. Try perturbing the initial point(s)`.

The histograms of the distribution are shown below:[image]
[image]

Comment: "if I'm given moments" **All** moments or just **some** moments? With all moments, build the characteristic function, take its inverse Fourier transform to get the `PDF`. Then use `ProbabilityDistribution` to define the distribution from the `PDF`.

Comment: If you only know a few sample moments **AND** you have a distribution in mind, then you can equate the sample moments to the theoretical moments and solve for the distribution parameters.  This is known as the "Method of Moments".  There are several examples on this site.  Here's one:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108052/estimate-parameters-of-a-derived-distribution/108075#108075.

Comment: Is this any different from your question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/635999/find-pdf-from-approximated-mgf ?

Comment: No. I don't have MGF, just a finite number of moments. I tried to use the method of moments, but Mathematica doesn't give a solution.

Comment: What *Mathematica* code and distribution did you use?

Comment: Mathematica 14.  And to use the method of moments, I need to know the distribution. But I don't know it.

Comment: I mean specifically what was the code you used.  Please add that code to your question.

Comment: @JimB , I've added the code.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I now see that for this particular Johnson distribution, 3 moments are not sufficient to obtain unique estimates of the parameters.  (This is typically not the case in that in practice 3 parameters requires just 3 moments.)  But for this Johnson distribution the 3rd moment is the cube of the ratio of the second to the first moment. This relationship is probably the reason for the error you're seeing. So very loosely, the first 3 moments only provide 2 of the necessary pieces of information to estimate the 3 parameters.

Comment: I can add more moments.

Comment: Also, you said that the 3rd moment is the cube of the ratio of the second to the first moment, but $\left(\frac{5.252267250245984}{1.2974425414}\right)^3$ is not equal to $112.50634898225843576187$.

Comment: I agree.  That means your moments and not from a Johnson distribution.  Here's the proof: `{M1, M2, M3} = Moment[JohnsonDistribution["SL", \[Gamma], \[Delta], 0, \[Lambda]], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}; (M2/M1)^3 - M3 // Simplify` results in 0.  The moments you provide don't result in anything close what is required for that Johnson distribution.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I think you have a good question but there just aren't enough details for anyone to provide an answer.  If you can generate a large number of samples, nonparametric density estimation (using `SmoothKernelDistribution` or `SmoothHistogram`) can provide a close approximation of the density.  If you need to estimate parameters, then you need to specify a plausible distribution.

Comment: But I think that the above distribution is close to `Johnson` and `LogNormal`. Thank you for telling about `SmoothKernelDistribution`,

Comment: If one fits a log normal with the first two moments (`sol = Solve[{j[1] == 1.2974425414,  j[2] == 5.252267250245984, \[Sigma] > 0}, {\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, Reals][[1]]; j[3] /. sol `) results in a 3rd moment of 66.3401 which is half of your 112.50634898225843576187.  So a log normal does not seem likely.

Comment: You are correct.